# Apache mod_rewrite https

Tags: apache2

does mod_rewrite makes an internal redirection when rewriting http to https or the client got a redirect response?
I would that all HTTP request to a specific port are interpreted as HTTPS (Apache), and this must be transparent to the client..

is that possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use port 443 - it defaults as 'HTTPS'

Comment: yes, i know, but can't use that port because the server is behind a load balancer that can't forward to 443. I just want to know if mod_rewrite does an internal sub-processing or send a redirect to client when rewriting HTTP to HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

It's a redirect - if you use a cert from a recognised CA it will be transparent.